# SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier / Discord Bot Coding

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord

I'm trying to code my own discord bot using node.js. I keep getting this error every time, and I can't tell what the problem is. I tried a lot of other ways to code, but it wouldn't work out. I even read what people did when they had something similar to this, yet again, nothing worked out.

This is the index.js file/code.

```
    const Discord = require('discord.js');

    const client = new Discord.Client({ partials: ["MESSAGE", "CHANNEL", "REACTION" ]});

    const prefix = '.';

    const fs = require('fs');

    client.command = new.Discord.Collection();

    const commandFiles = fs.readdirSync('./commands/').filter(file => file.endsWith('.js'));
    for(const file of commandFiles){
        const command = require(`./commands/${file}`);

        client.commands.set(command.name, command);
    }

    client.once('ready', () => {
        console.log('Ready!');
    });

    client.on('message', message => {
        if (!message.content.startsWith(prefix) || message.author.bot ) return;

        const args = message.content.slice(prefix.length).split(/ +/);
        const command = args.shift().toLowerCase();

        if (command === 'clear') {
            client.commands.get('clear').execute(message, args);
        }

        if (command === 'reactionrole') {
            client.commands.get('reactionrole').execute(message, args, Discord, client);
        } 

    });

    client.login('TOKEN');
```

This is the error I would get.

```
    /Users/User/Desktop/discordbot/index.js:9
    client.command = new.Discord.Collection();
                         ^^^^^^^

    SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
        at wrapSafe (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:979:16)
        at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1027:27)
        at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1092:10)
        at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:928:32)
        at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:769:14)
        at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:72:12)
        at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:47
```

Comment: `new.Discord.Collection();` -> `new Discord.Collection();`

Answer (score 0):

The problem you have is here:

```
client.command = new.Discord.Collection();
```

You have an extra `.` and missing a  , so it should be like this:

```
client.command = new Discord.Collection();
```

Answer (score 0):

The syntax is: `new`, followed by whitespace, then the thing to create an instance of. There's no dot (`.`) anywhere in the syntax. See:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/new

Just use the same syntax as the first, correct usage of `new` in your code.